Problem with SSL Provider when connecting to SQL Server
When I tried to connect to a database server, a dialog appear:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 1  0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

If I click 'Yes', I could access to SSMS. But when I connect to SQL Server from Visual Studio 2022, I can't load the server.

Does it let you specify connection string parameters? You want TrustServerCertificate=true (or possibly Trust Server Certificate=true, although the docs suggest either will be accepted)

@MarcGravell Or a better idea, just install a proper trusted certificate.
